# how to interpret z-score of a column to find the distribution type?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, normal-distribution

I have a pandas dataframe with couple of columns.

I calculated z-score based on mean and standard deviation for one of the column.

Now, i would like to know what distribution based on z-score? Based on histogram i can tell its normal distribution.

Is there an programmatic to tell distribution type based on z-score?

I'm new to statistics. so maybe i'm missing something very simple.

**Sample code:**

```
df[col_zscore] = (df[column] - df[column].mean())/df[column].std(ddof=0)
```

Comment: You can estimate with a given probability if a distribution could be xxx, but you can never be sure ;)

Comment: @mozway could you please add some more detail about your comments? Like how to estimate

Comment: this question might be more appropriate for [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), but you could first read about [normality tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test)

Comment: @mozway do you mean calculating p value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If distribution is normal distribution, from `68–95–99.7` rule,  `68%` of the  `df[col_zscore]` will be between `-1` to `1` , `95%` between `-2` to `2`, and `99.7%` between `-3` to `3`. On the other hand extreme, the z score is infinity for a fixed number.

You can check if it is *close to* normal or a fixed value by the following function:

```
import math
def three_sigma_rule(input):
  input = input.tolist()
  one_sigma = (len([ele for ele in input if -1<ele<1])) / len(input) * 100
  two_sigma = (len([ele for ele in input if -2<ele<2])) / len(input) * 100
  three_sigma = (len([ele for ele in input if -3<ele<3])) / len(input) * 100
  print("Percentage of the z-score between -1 to 1: {0}%".format(one_sigma))
  print("Percentage of the z-score between -2 to 2: {0}%".format(two_sigma))
  print("Percentage of the z-score between -3 to 3: {0}%".format(three_sigma))
  condition1 = math.isclose(one_sigma,68,rel_tol=0.1)
  condition2 = math.isclose(two_sigma,95,rel_tol=0.1)
  condition3 = math.isclose(three_sigma,99.7,rel_tol=0.1)
  condition4 = np.isnan(input).all()
  if condition1 and  condition2 and condition3:
    print("It is normal distribution.")      
  if condition4:
    print("It is fixed value.")
```

Let's generate some random numbers:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np

  n = 100000
  df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    a=np.random.normal(5,3,size=n),
    b=np.random.uniform(low=-100, high=10000, size=n),
    c=np.random.uniform(low=5, high=5, size=n),
  ))
  df['a_zscore'] = (df['a'] - df['a'].mean())/df['a'].std(ddof=0)
  df['b_zscore'] = (df['b'] - df['b'].mean())/df['b'].std(ddof=0)
  df['c_zscore'] = (df['c'] - df['c'].mean())/df['c'].std(ddof=0)
```

Output of `three_sigma_rule(df['a_zscore'])`:

[image]